# Collections holding different Types Simultaneously

Tags: c++, ruby

Traditionally, I've programmed in c++ and Java, and I'm now beginning to learn ruby.

My question then is, how do languages like ruby internally implement their array and hash data structures in such a way that they can hold any type at the same time? I know that in Java, the fact that every class is derived from object, could be one way to implement this, but I was wondering if there was another way. For example, in c++, if I wanted to implement a dynamic array that could simultaneously hold multiple types of values (of no relation), how could I do this?

To clarify, I'm not referring to generic programming or templates, as those simply create a new collection interface for a type. I'm referring to a structure such as this:

`array = [1, "hello", someClass];`

Comment: `in c++, if I wanted to implement a dynamic array that could simultaneously hold multiple types of values (of no relation), how could I do this?` You would wrap them in some sort of variant class, e.g. `boost::any`. The difficulty would be mostly in figuring out afterwards what type each element is - unlike Java (and possibly Ruby - I'm not really familiar with that) C++ doesn't have reflection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of them do roughly the same as you'd get in C++ by creating a `vector` (or `list`, `deque`, etc.) of `boost::any`, or something similar.

That is to say, they basically attach some tag to each type of object as it's stored in memory. When they store an object, they store the tag. When they read an object, they look at the tag to figure out what kind of object that is. Of course, they also handle most of this internally, so you don't have to write the code to figure out what kind of object you've just retrieved from the collection.

In case it's not clear: the "tag" is just a unique number assigned to each type. If the system you're dealing with has primitive types, it'll normally pre-assign a type number to each of them. Likewise, each class you create gets a unique number assigned to it.

To do that in C++, you'd normally create a central registry of tags. When you register a type, you receive a unique number back that you use to tag objects of that type. When a language supports this directly, it automates the process of registering types and choosing a unique tag for each.

Although this is probably the most common method of implementing such things, it's definitely not the only one. Just for example, it's also possible to designate specific ranges of storage for particular types. When you allocate an object of a given type, it's always allocated from that type's address range. When you create a collection of "objects", you're really not storing the objects themselves, but instead storing something that contains the address of the object. Since objects are segregated by address you can figure out the type of the object based on the value of the pointer.

Answer (score 4):

In the [MRI](https://github.com/ruby/ruby) interpreter, a ruby value is stored as a pointer type which points to a data structure storing the class of the value and any data associated with the value. Since pointers are always the same size, (`sizeof(unsigned long)` usually), it is possible. To answer your question about C++, it is impossible in C++ to determine the class of an object given it's location in memory, so it wouldn't be possible unless you had something like this:

```
enum object_class { STRING, ARRAY, MAP, etc... };

struct TaggedObject {
  enum object_class klass;
  void *value;
}
```

and passed around `TaggedObject *` values. That is pretty much what ruby does internally.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do that :-

You can define a common interface for all the elements and make a container of those. For example:

```
class Common { /* ... */ };  // the common interface.
```

You can use container of `void*` :-

```
vector<void*> common;        // this would rather be too low level.
                             // you have to use cast very much.
```

And then the best approach I think is using an Any class, such as Boost::Any :-

```
vector<boost::any> v;
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for something called type erasure. The simplest way to do this in C++ is with [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/any.html):

```
std::vector<boost::any> stuff;
stuff.push_back(1);
stuff.push_back(std::string("hello"));
stuff.push_back(someClass);
```

Of course with `any`, you're extremely limited in what you can do with your `stuff` since you have to personally remember everything you put into it.

A more common use-case of heterogeneous containers might be a series of callbacks. The standard class `std::function<R(Args...)>` is, in fact, a type-erased functor:

```
void foo() { .. }

struct SomeClass {
    void operator()() { .. }
};

std::vector<std::function<void()>> callbacks;
callbacks.push_back(foo);
callbacks.push_back(SomeClass{});
callbacks.push_back([]{ .. });
```

Here, we're adding three objects of different types (a `void(*)()`, a `SomeClass`, and some lambda) to the same container - which we do by *erasing* the type. So we can still do:

```
for (auto& func : callbacks) {
    func();
}
```

And that will do the right thing in each of the three objects... no virtuals needed!

Answer (score 2):

Others have explained ways you can do this in C++.

There are various ways to solve this problem. To answer your question about how does languages such as Ruby solve this, without going into details of exactly how Ruby solves it, they use a structure that contains type information. For example, we could do that in C++ something like this:

```
enum TypeKind { None, Int, Float, String }; // May need a few more?

class TypeBase
{
   protected:
     TypeKind kind;
   public:
     TypeBase(TypeKind k) : kind(k) { }
     virtual ~TypeBase() {};
     TypeKind type() { return kind; }
};


class TypeInt : public TypeBase
{
   private: 
      int value;
   public:
      TypeInt(int v) : value(v), TypeBase(Int) {}
};

class TypeFloat : public TypeBase
{
   private: 
      double value;
   public:
      TypeFloat(double v) : value(v), TypeBase(Float) {}
};

class TypeString : public TypeBase
{
   private: 
      std::string value;
   public:
      TypeString(std::string v) : value(v), TypeBase(String) {}
};
```

(To make it useful, we probably need some more methods for the `TypeXxx` class, but I don't feel like typing for another hour... ;) )

And then somewhere, it determines the type, e.g.

```
Token t = getNextToken();
TypeBase *ty;
if (t.type == IntegerToken)
{
   ty = new(TypeInt(stoi(t.str));
}
else if (t.type == FloatToken)
{
   ty = new(TypeFloat(stod(t.str));
}
else if (t.type == StringToken)
{
   ty = new(TypeString(t.str));
}
```

Of course, we'd also need to deal with variables and various other scenarios, but the essence of it is that the language can keep track of (and sometimes mutate) the value that is stored.

Most languages in the general category where Ruby, PHP, Python, etc are, will have this sort of mechanism, and all variables are stored in some sort of indirect way. The above is just one possible solution, I can think of at least half a dozen other ways to do this, but they are variations on the theme of "store data together with type information".

(And by the way, `boost::any` also does something along the lines of the above, more or less....)

Comment: I thought that c++ classes already contained the type information needed to solve this problem? To some extent anyway. I know that the primitives wouldn't fail into this category, but for class types, I thought an internal struct of information already existed

Thank you for the answer, it certainly makes sense!

Comment: Well, the compiler does not provide information about "what the type is" that is useful to the application as such. [And I just realized I was missing that part - will edit that in]. There is information to make `dynamic_cast` and similar functionality work, and if you have RTTI (runtime type information), you can query if a particular type `isa` some type - but that's typically not useful for this purpose.

Comment: @Barry: Can you detail where my implementation is dramatically different from `boost::any`? Although I haven't spent hours analyzing exactly how it works, it seems to use a combination of a `placeholder` which is a baseclass for a templated content class called `holder` (and if it's NULL, it's an `empty` object). It then uses the C++ standard `type_info` class to provide what I use an `enum TypeKind` for, but generally I'd say it's the same overall concept. Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: @MatsPetersson Yes placeholder/holder, but I'd call type_info pretty different than a named enum tag. It doesn't know what type it is in the sense that a tag would provide... it can only tell if if the type you try to `any_cast` it on is correct or not. What you're describing is closer to `boost::variant`.

Comment: But surely that's a minor detail, not "does not work like this"? But I admit I may be confusing `boost::variant` and `boost::any` to some degree. My main point is that `boost::any` and (I think, as yet again, I haven't actually studied the code much at all) `boost::variant` is using a similar basic principle to what I describe. How much you need a tag, how the tag is used, etc, largely depends on exactly what you plan to do with it later. I'd say at a fundamental leve, `type_info` is also a form of tag, just less useful in a `switch` perhaps...

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, the answer is rather simple: that array *doesn't* contain values of different types, they are all of the same type. They are all objects.

Ruby is dynamically typed, the idea of an array that is statically constrained to only hold elements of the same type doesn't even make sense.

For a statically typed language, the question is, how much do you want it to be like Ruby? Do you want it to be actually dynamically typed? Then you need to implement a dynamic type in your language (if it doesn't already have one, like C♯’s `dynamic`).

Otherwise, if you want a statically typed heterogenous list, such a thing is usually called an `HList`. There's a very nice implementation for Scala in the Shapeless library, for example.